# Weird “Direct-ES” Wi-Fi connection appearing on device near my desktop

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

So for a while I've noticed this, but I never knew what it meant.
There is a hotspot called:

```
Direct-ES[name of machine here]msNM
```

Any idea what it is?

Comment: Somebody with a PC sharing their internet connection as a hotspot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PC’s Wi-Fi interface supports a recent-ish technology called “[Wi-Fi Direct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct)” (one of many ways to do direct peer-to-peer Wi-Fi connections without an AP), but your other device does not (or is buggy).

Devices that know about Wi-Fi Direct know to filter out these network names that start with “Direct-xx…”, but older/simpler devices don’t know any better and just display them.